# »Mein Fahrrad ist kaputt geworden« Ist das schlechtes Deutsch?

Tags: style

In einer [Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/38959/1487) zu einer anderen Frage schrieb ich sinngemäß:

> Der Satz »Mein Fahrrad ist kaputt geworden« ist völlig korrektes Deutsch.

In einem [Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38958/is-this-a-dative-of-possession-is-this-syntax-common/38959?noredirect=1#comment96090_38959) wurde genau das bestritten.

Ich persönlich halte den Satz »Mein Fahrrad ist kaputt geworden« aber weder grammatikalisch noch stilistisch für bedenklich.

Was genau ist an diesem Satz auszusetzen?

Liegt hier möglicherweise wieder eine geographische Variation vor?

Dort, wo ich aufgewachsen bin, **werden** Dinge groß, schön, kaputt und alt:

> Iris ist schon groß geworden.
>   *Iris ist schon groß gegangen.
>
> Das Bild ist schön geworden.
>   *Das Bild ist schön gegangen.
>
> Mein Fahrrad ist kaputt geworden.
>   Mein Fahrrad ist kaputt gegangen.
>
> Joseph ist auch schon alt geworden.
>   *Joseph ist auch schon alt gegangen.

Den Ausdruck »etwas geht kaputt« kenne ich natürlich auch, mir erscheint es aber natürlicher, »etwas wird kaputt« zu sagen.

---

**Nachtrag:**

Zustandspassiv:

> Das Bild ist schön.
>   Das Fahrrad ist kaputt.

Bilde aus beiden Sätzen den Vorgangspassiv.

Comment: An den -1-voter: Warum ist das eine schlechte Frage?

Comment: Es gibt das Verb _kaputtgehen_ (http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kaputtgehen), aber (noch) nicht das Verb _kaputtwerden_. PS: Ich habe die Frage nicht heruntergewertet.

Comment: Was sollen die Sternchen aussagen? Wo sagt man "Das Bild ist schön gegangen"? (X alt gegangen/groß gegangen).

Comment: Die Sternchen bedeuten, dass dieser Satz nicht korrekt ist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Im deutschen Sprachraum, den ich kenne, ist

> Mein Fahrrad ist kaputtgegangen

die akzeptierte Ausdrucksweise, wohingegen

> Mein Fahrrad ist kaputt geworden

so unüblich ist, dass es als falsch (oder irritierend) empfunden wird.

Das schließt nicht aus, dass es Gegenden oder Milieus gibt, in denen man so spricht. Selbst mir geht es so, dass ich mich, wenn ich den Satz 50 mal hintereinander aufsage, daran gewöhne und mir das Schräge daran nicht mehr auffällt.

"Richtig" oder "falsch" sind hier vielleicht nicht die richtigen Kategorien. Aber ein Zeitungsredakteur oder Buch-Lektor, also jemand, der sich an etablierten Standards aus der Schriftsprachkultur orientiert, würde den Ausdruck gleichwohl bemängeln und eine Änderung zu "kaputtgegangen" verlangen.

Wohlgeformte Sätze sind weiterhin

> Mein Fahrrad ist kaputt.
>
> Der Hans hat mein Fahrrad kaputtgemacht.
>
> Mein Fahrrad stand im Winter draußen, jetzt ist die Kette kaputt.
>
> Ich hatte so viele Termine heute, jetzt bin ich total kaputt.

Bei letzterer Verwendung des Wortes "kaputt" im Sinne von "ermüdet" kann man übrigens "machen" nicht sagen. "Kaputtmachen" bezieht sich ausschließlich auf Schäden an technischen Geräten, nicht auf Erschöpfung bei Lebewesen.)

---

**Nachtrag 1 - Das sagt die Wissenschaft**

Man findet das Thema kurz behandelt in:

- Ljudmila Geist, Björn Rothstein (Hg): Kopulaverben und Kopulasätze: intersprachliche und intrasprachliche Aspekte. Niemeyer (Linguistische Arbeiten), Tübingen 2007. (Seite 11).

Hier wird *Härtl (2005)* zitiert mit der Auffassung, dass der Ausdruck *kaputt werden* grammatisch zwar zulässig, jedoch durch *kaputt gehen* **lexikalisch blockiert** sei (siehe unten letzte Zeile).

[image: Buch-Auszug zur Frage des Kaputtwerdens]

**Nachtrag 2 - Ähnliche Fälle**

Vielleicht ist die Abneigung eines größeren Teils der deutschsprechenden Gemeinschaft, *kaputt werden* zu sagen, auch im Zusammenhang zu sehen mit ähnlichen Konstrukten, bei denen *werden* ebenfalls nicht verwendet wird:

> Mein Schlüssel ist flötengegangen.
>
> Die Veranstaltung ist badengegangen.
>
> Die USA sind den Bach runtergegangen

nicht aber:

> *Mein Schlüssel ist flöten geworden.
>
> *Die Veranstaltung ist baden geworden.
>
> *Die USA sind den Bach runter geworden

Comment: »Jetzt bin ich total kaputt.« ist ein Satz im Zustandspassiv. Angenommen, du wolltest beschreiben, wie du in diesen Zustand geraten bist: Wie lautet dieser Satz im Vorgangspassiv. Mein Vorschlag (mit kleinen stilistischen Veränderungen): »Ich habe ständig so viele Termine, wenn das noch lange so weiter geht, **werde ich noch total kaputt hier**.«

Comment: Hm... ja... interessant. Erneut würde ich sagen: In meinem Umfeld würde man das so nicht sagen ("kaputt" + "werden" scheint irgendwie tabu zu sein); aber erneut muss ich zugeben: wenn ich mir den Satz oft genug anhöre, gewöhne ich mich auch daran.

Comment: "Die vielen Termine machen mich kaputt."

Comment: @HubertSchölnast "Jetzt bin ich total kaputt" ist **kein** Zustandspassiv - genausowenig, wie "Ich bin blond" eins ist. Das Zustandspassiv wird gebildet aus einer Form von *sein* und einem Partizip - "kaputt" ist kein Partizip.

Answer (score 8):

Ich gebe Dir Recht, dass grammatisch oder logisch an *kaputt werden* nichts auszusetzen ist. Für mich hier in Berlin ist *kaputtgehen* aber so dominant, dass *kaputt werden* falsch und komisch klingt. Bei Dir ist das anscheinend anders. Das ist interessant, und es ist sicher gut, dass wir nun beide wissen, dass es anderswo anders ist. Viel mehr gibt es dazu wahrscheinlich nicht zu sagen, außer dass jemand die örtliche und zeitliche Verteilung untersuchen könnte.

Answer (score 3):

Nein, *kaputt werden* ist kein schlechtes Deutsch, nur ungewöhnlich (zumindest in Deutschland).

[image]

<sup>Goggle Ngram</sup>

In Deutschland kennen wir folgende umgangssprachliche Konstrukte:

- kaputt sein
- kaputt machen / kaputtmachen
- kaputt gehen / kaputtgehen

*Kaputt werden* kommt nicht vor.

Interessanterweise kann in Österreich offenbar etwas [tschari **gehn**](http://www.ostarrichi.org/word-12637-verlorengehen_kaputt_werden-tschari_gehn.html) und dadurch [kaputt **werden**](http://www.ostarrichi.org/word-12637-verlorengehen_kaputt_werden-tschari_gehn.html).

Comment: Vgl. auch [_»hops sein«_](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hops_umgangssprachlich_verloren) u. [_»hopsgehen«_](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hopsgehen)

Comment: @Pollitzer aber niemals *hops werden* ;)

Comment: Will ich auch nicht gesagt haben, war nur eine Ergänzung zu deinen umgangssprachlichen Konstrukten.

Answer (score 2):

Bei

> Iris ist schon groß geworden.
>   Das Bild ist schön geworden.
>   Joseph ist auch schon alt geworden.

beziehst du darauf, dass etwas schon ist ("schön sein", "groß sein", ...), und beschreibst gleichzeitig, dass es nicht schon immer so war, sondern sich dorthin entwickelt hat.

Bei "Das Fahrrad ist kaputt gegangen" hingegen konjugierst du das Wort "[kaputtgehen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kaputtgehen)".

Es ist zwar auch möglich, "kaputt sein" zu nutzen, um den Zustand des Fahrrads zu beschreiben.

> Das Fahrrad ist kaputt.

Allerdings gibt es hier keinen natürlichen Prozess, der dazu führen könnte, dass das Fahrrad kaputt ist. Iris hingegen wächst von alleine, jedes Bild wird irgendwann mal gemalt und Joseph wird auch von alleine älter.

Es gibt also keinen klaren, eindeutigen Prozess für "kaputt gehen" - du kannst das Fahrrad beschädigen, es kann verrosten, oder durch mechanische Mängel auseinanderfallen. "Das Fahrrad wurde kaputt" ist also falsch, da hier nicht klar ist, was gemeint ist.

> Das Fahrrad wurde beschädigt.

ist hingegen wieder möglich.

Was dich vermutlich dazu verleitet hat, anzunehmen, dass "Mein Fahrrad ist kaputt geworden" korrekt wäre, ist, dass es (umgangssprachlich?) das Verb "[kaputtmachen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kaputtmachen)" gibt. Dementsprechend wäre auch

> Mein Fahrrad wurde kaputt gemacht.
>   oder
>   Mein Fahrrad ist kaputt gemacht (ge-?)worden.

wieder korrekt. Letzteres hört sich aber reichlich bescheiden an, ich würde eher die erste Version verwenden.

Ich hoffe ich konnte dir weiterhelfen :)

Comment: Ein Fahrrad kann sehr wohl von alleine kaputt werden. Kette ein fabrikneues Fahrrad an einen Zaun und lass es dort zehn Jahre hängen. Du wirst danach feststellen, das es kaputt ist. Also ist es kaputt geworden, ohne dass es jemand kaputt gemacht hat. Beim Bild ist das genau nicht der Fall. Das wird von alleine nicht schöner als es ohnehin schon war. Da muss schon jemand zum Pinsel greifen um es schön zu machen.

Comment: Ich bin auch kein Deutschprofessor oder so, das ist nur meine Einschätzung. Das Fahrrad am Zaun geht übrigens auch nicht komplett selbstständig kaputt, sondern durch Regen & anderes Wetter. Wenn du es in einem trockenen Raum einschließt, sollte es auch nach 10 Jahren noch in mehr oder weniger einwandfreiem Zustand sein.

Comment: Das Bild wird auch nicht komplett selbstständig schön, sondern nur durch die Tätigkeit des Malers. Wenn du das unbemalte Bild in einem Raum einschließt, und keinen Maler daran lässt, sollte es auch nach 10 Jahren noch in mehr oder weniger unbemaltem Zustand (also nicht schön) sein.

Comment: Ich habe übrigens niemals von »kaputtmachen« gesprochen, sondern von »kaputt werden«. Das ist etwas anderes. Beim Kaputtmachen braucht man einen Täter, der etwas kaputt macht. Wenn etwas kaputt wird, braucht man niemanden, der das extra macht. Das passiert von alleine. Beispiel: Eine Glühbirne, die man einmal einschaltet und dann nie wieder ausschaltet, wird nach ein paar tausend Stunden ganz von selber kaputt, ohne dass da noch jemand irgend etwas besonderes machen müsste.

Comment: Beim Bild ist aber implizit klar, wie das Bild schön geworden ist. Beim Fahrrad gibt es hingegen diverse Möglichkeiten, wieso es kaputt gegangen ist.  
Dass du nie von "kaputtmachen" gesprochen hast, ist mir klar. "Kaputtmachen" *wäre* aber richtig, während "kaputt werden" entweder falsch ist - oder es ist richtig, hört sich aber so besch*ssen an, dass du es am Besten einfach nicht verwendest.

Comment: Wenn der Glühfaden einer Glühbirne durchgebrannt ist, kann sie nicht mehr leuchten. So eine Glühbirne *ist* kaputt. Auch in diesem Fall ist implizit klar, wie sie diesen Zustand angenommen hat, also wie sie kaputt *geworden* ist.

Comment: Liebe Kollegen, ich meine, die Suche nach semantisch-logischen Gründen, warum "kaputtwerden" ein zulässiger Ausdruck ist oder nicht ist, führt zu keinem Ergebnis. Ich denke, die Frage ist eine der Pragmatik: Man sagt es halt so, oder man sagt es so halt nicht. Es gibt auch andere Ausdrücke, bei denen man sich wundern könnte, warum man sie so sagt und nicht anders. Die Welt hat sich halt so entwickelt. Sie hätte sich auch anders entwickeln können. Zebras sind schwarz-weiß, sie könnten auch braun-weiß sein. Sie sind es halt nicht.

Comment: die Glühbirne kann durchbrennen, runterfallen, verrosten, ...

Comment: Ich bin mir unsicher, ob man nicht in Extremfällen doch sagen kann "kaputt geworden", und zwar wenn es nicht im üblichen Gebrauch (Verkehr + Unfall oder Verschleiß, Rost) kaputt geht, sondern es steht auf der Straße und die Mure rollt drüber. Es wird ausgebuddelt und ist massiv kaputt - nicht ein kleiner Defekt, sondern alles verbogen, vieles abgerissen. Eher würde man da wohl sagen "zu Schrott geworden".

Answer (score 0):

Korrekt hin oder her, *werden* ist durch seine Funktion als Hilfsverb für andere Funktionen meist nur zweite Wahl und wäre zu meiner Schulzeit im Aufsatz vermutlich mit einer roten Wellenlinie und dem Vermerk "Ausdruck" zurückgekommen. Also möglicherweise handelt es sich um eine regionale Prägung. In praktisch allen Fällen existieren ja auch bessere Lösungen:

- groß werden → wachsen
- alt werden → altern
- schön werden (von einem Bild) → gut gelingen

*Kaputt werden* würde ich bei einem Kind hinnehmen, das sich sprachlich noch entwickelt oder keine Vorstellung davon hat, was am Fahrrad kaputt ist. Ansonsten gibt es mit

- ist verrostet, verschlissen
- hat einen Platten, einen Achter, einen defekten Dynamo, eine verrostete Kette, abgenutzte Bremsbacken, einen gerissenen Seilzug

griffigere Formulierungen, zudem *Mein Fahrrad ist kaputt* den Sachverhalt in allgemeiner Form klarstellt. Dass ein kaputtes Fahrrad so *geworden* ist, braucht man niemandem zu erklären, da der Neuzustand als intakt vorausgesetzt werden kann.