# Warum *geht* etwas kaputt/verloren/vorbei? (Warum »gehen«?)

Tags: word-usage

In einer [anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/38960/1487) habe ich bereits gefragt, ob die Phrase »etwas wird kaputt« gutes Deutsch ist. (Die ähnliche Phrase »etwas geht kaputt« scheint ja im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum gängig zu sein.)

Hier möchte ich aber wissen, warum in dieser Phrase ausgerechnet das Verb *gehen* das Verb »werden« verdrängt hat. Bei der Suche nach ähnlichen Beispielen fiel mir nur das ein:

> Meine Schlüssel **gingen verloren.**
>   Die Krise **geht vorbei.**

<sub>(In einigen österreichischen Dialekten gibt es auch noch die Phrase *»etwas geht tschari«* (Danke, Takkat, für diesen Hinweis!), die man am ehesten mit »etwas verfällt« oder »etwas geht den Bach runter« wiedergeben kann: »Die XY-Bank wäre fast *tschari* gegangen, wenn die EU sie nicht gerettet hätte.« In anderen Gegenden scheint es auch die mir unbekannte Phrase »etwas geht hops« zu geben. Ich bleibe hier aber lieber bei standarddeutschen Phrasen.)</sub>

Interessant ist, dass *kaputt, verloren* und *vorbei* zu verschiedenen Wortarten gehören:

- **kaputt**
  Adjektiv

  > Warum gibst du mir ein **kaputtes** Handy?
- **verloren**
  Partizip, also ein Zwitter zwischen Verb und Adjektiv

  > Verb: Ich habe gestern mein Handy **verloren.**
  >   Adjektiv: Das **verlorene** Handy lag unter dem Tisch.
- **vorbei**
  Adverb (lokal oder temporal)

  > lokal: In der Menge sah Monika an ihm **vorbei** und nahm ihn gar nicht wahr.
  >   temporal: Du bist zu spät, die Vorstellung ist schon **vorbei.**

Alle drei Wörter kann man adverbiell verwenden, also als Ergänzung des Prädikats, dessen Verb eine Form von *sein* ist. Dadurch entsteht ein Zustandspassiv:

> Das Handy **ist kaputt.**
>   Die Schlacht **ist verloren.**
>   Das Fest **ist vorbei.**

Trotzdem wird in diesen drei Fällen der Vorgangspassiv (von regionalen Ausnahmen abgesehen) nicht wie sonst üblich mit *werden*, sondern mit *gehen* gebildet:

> Das Handy <del>wird</del> **geht kaputt.**
>   Die Schlacht <del>wird</del> **geht verloren.**
>   Das Fest <del>wird</del> **geht vorbei.**

Warum ist das so? Warum verwendet man hier ausgerechnet das Verb *»gehen«*, und nicht ein anderes Verb?

Comment: Interessant wäre, wenn jemand ein historisches Textkorpus hätte, in dem er nachspüren könnte, wann und wo solche "xxxxx gehen"-Wendungen zum ersten Mal nachweisbar auftreten. Gibt es das schon in mittelalterlichen deutschen Texten? War es da vielleicht sogar noch mehr verbreitet, und es verliert sich mit der Zeit?

Comment: Witzigerweise fällt mir ein, dass ich viele jüngere Leute beobachte, die bei Videospielen davon sprechen "tot zu gehen". So falsch es sich anfänglich anhört, entspricht es den genannten Kriterien.

Comment: @Clijsters Mein Vater würde auch "totgehen" verwenden, aber der ist der Videospiele eher unverdächtig.

Comment: @Robert ich denke auch nicht, dass die Ursache die Videospiele sind. Ich denke, viele junge Menschen haben nur mit dem Tod keinen anderen Berührungspunkt.

Comment: Auch hier nochmal: Deine Beispielsätze mit "kaputt" und "vorbei" sind *keine Passiva* (weder Zustands- noch Vorgangspassiv), weil kein Partizip drinsteckt, sondern ganz normale Kopulasätze. Ein Passiv wird **immer** mit einem Hilfsverb und einem Partizip gebildet - "kaputt" und "vorbei" sind keine Partizipien!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wie die [Grimms ganz ausführlich darlegen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GG04934#XGG04934) (und hier nur knapp und stark gekürzt wiedergegeben werden kann), benutzen wir *gehen* schon lange (möglicherweise noch vor dem altgotischen *gangan*) unter anderem für alle erdenklichen Arten einer Fortbewegung oder auch ganz allgemein Bewegung. Dies durchaus auch im übertragenen Sinn und wenn etwas von einem Zustand in den anderen über**geht**.

Ein Gegner **geht** zu Boden. So **geht** auch ein Krug zum Grund - und dann **geht** er entzwei (man drückt dadurch sie vermeintlich selbständige Bewegung  aus) und ist schließlich zugrunde **gegangen**.

So eine innewohnende Bewegung spielt auch ein Rolle, wenn wir sagen *der Fleck **geht** nur schwer wieder weg*. Oder auch, wenn die Zeit unaufhaltsam wie von selbst voran**schreitet** kann man sagen, sie **geht** vorbei.

Genau dieser intrinsische Bewegungsmoment spielt auch eine Rolle, wenn wir sagen etwas ist **kaputt gegangen**, als sei es ganz von selbst in diesen Zustand übergetreten. Auch wenn wir beteiligt waren, schwingt in der Aussage *es ist mir kaputt gegangen* immer ein wenig auch eine Unschuldsbehauptung mit. Der Gegenstand könnte doch mit seinem eigenen *Gang* ein wenig zum Unglück beigetragen haben.

Comment: Es geht voran. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JztCkQ4ubQ

Comment: @CarstenS: jaaaa - genau!

Comment: Das ist ein wichtiger Beitrag. Aber bleibt nicht letztlich doch die Frage offen, warum gerade "gehen" diese Rolle übernimmt? Zwei Einwände nämlich: Erstens bezeichnet ja auch "werden" einen Übergang, eine innewohnende Bewegung. Zweitens hätten wohl auch andere Verben der Bewegung diese Rolle übernehmen können: *Mein Fahrrad ist kaputtgelaufen* wäre ja von identischem Aussagewert - sagte man es denn.

Comment: *"ein nach form und gehalt überaus reich entwickeltes wort, dessen erschöpfende behandlung ein werk für sich wäre."* ([Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GG04934#XGG04934)) - man könnte eine eigene Abhandlung schreiben (bei *werden* ist IMO der Bewegungsaspekt nicht oder nur wenig vorhanden) - `<WITZ`Ich habe mein Fahrrad *kaputtgetreten* kann man schon sagen `/WITZ>`

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ich pflichte deinem Argument dem Grunde nach bei, aber *gehen* und *laufen* sind zwei verschiedene Verben mit unterschiedlicher Bedeutung, zumindest im Süden des deutschen Sprachraums, dort ist *laufen* nämlich ein Synonym für *rennen*. In Österreich lernen Kleinkinder nicht laufen, sondern gehen. Erst wenn sie einigermaßen gut gehen können, können sie es mit dem Laufen versuchen.

Comment: @Takkat: »Werden« enthält zwar tatsächlich keinen Bezug zu einer Bewegung, interessanterweise beinhaltet das Verb »machen«, das eine gewisse thematische Nähe zu »werden« aufweist, diesen Bewegungsbezug aber sehr wohl (»Sie *müssen* an der Ampel nach links.« »Ich *muss* nach Hause.«)

Comment: @Hubert, zum Bewegungsaspekt von "müssen". Interessante Beobachtung. Doch könnte man auch behaupten, dass diese Sätze auf einer reinen Ellipsis beruhen (Auslassung von "gehen") und dass der Bewegungsaspekt somit nicht am "Müssen" hängt, sondern vom mitgedachten "Gehen" getragen wird. (Aber, okay, man kann  natürlich auch sagen, dass das "Gehen" seinen Bewegungsaspekt ans "Müssen" abgegetreten hat.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Das war hier schon mal Thema: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/22622/1487

Answer (score 2):

Meine Interpretation hierzu ist, daß durch das "gehen" ("kaputt gehen", "vorüber gehen", "verloren gehen") eben der Über-"Gang" von einem Zustand ("heil", "gegenwärtig", "präsent" in einen anderen (gegenteiligen) Zustand angezeigt wird.

Es hat also weniger mit der konkreten Wortart (Adjektiv, Adverb, ...) zu tun, als vor allem mit der Beschreibung des transitiven Vorgangs.

Answer (score 0):

Warum ausgerechnet "gehen"? Du hast in deiner anderen Frage ja schon gezeigt, dass es mit anderen Verben auch geht, immerhin nicht überall verbreitet. Vielleicht ist das eine Nord-Süd-Sache? Wir sagen ja auf schwedisch auch gerade "gå sönder", also mit gehen. Veilleicht hat es mit dem intransitiven Charakter von "kaputtieren" zu tun? Immerhin sagt man jedoch umgangssprachlich wohl "hin werden".

> Die Zeitung wird hin, wenn du sie in der Badewanne liest.

Comment: Dies doch aber allerhöchsten in (südlichen?) Dialekten. Schrift- und standardsprachlich habe ich noch nie gehört bzw. gelesen, dass eine Sache "hin wird".

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Danke, dies verstärkt meine Vermutung, dass es um eine Verschiedenheit mit einem Gradient quer über die Latituden handelt

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: http://www.wienerzeitung.at/meinungen/glossen/878817_Alles-ist-hin.html Der Titel dieses Artikels bezieht sich auf eines der berühmtesten Wienerliedern, das manchmal auch als Kinderlied klassifiziert wird: »Oh, du lieber Augustin«. Siehe auch https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/hin Bedeutung 3b.

Comment: @Hubert. Das ist aber auch der einzige Satz mit "ist hin", der in einer Zeitung vorkommen wird - eine zitierte Liedzeile. Doch in einem normalen Text? Würde da stehen "Trumps Regierung jetzt endgültig hin"?