# Einem reichen Manne, dem wurde seine Frau krank

Tags: grammar-identification

> Einem reichen Manne, dem wurde seine Frau krank.

Das ist der allererste Satz von Aschenputtel und ich würde gerne verstehen, was hier vor sich geht, weil die Grammatik ein bisschen altertümlich ist. Meines Wissens bedeutet *Einem Manne seine Frau* "die Frau des Mannes", aber wieso schiebt man hier ein *dem* ein? So ähnelt das einem Relativsatz, aber es ist kein Relativsatz.

> Einem reichen Manne seine Frau wurde krank.

würde in meinen Augen mehr Sinn ergeben.

Comment: Heute würde man das nicht mehr so ausdrücken. "Die Frau eines reichen Mannes wurde krank" wäre die aktuelle Variante. Der Satzbeginn "Einem reichen Manne" legt aber den Fokus auf den Mann, dem etwas widerfuhr, nicht auf die Frau. Etwas besser als der Orignaltext wäre noch "Einem reichen Manne wurde seine Frau krank", nach dem Muster  "Jemanden wurde etwas angetan". Interessant ist übrigens, dass die Formulierung so erst ab der 2. Auflage 1819 auftaucht. In der Erstausgabe von 1812 steht "Es war einmal ein reicher Mann,

Comment: der lebte lange Zeit vergnügt mit seiner Frau, und sie hatten ein einziges Töchterlein zusammen. Da ward die Frau krank." Vgl. https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Aschenputtel .

Comment: Zum gleichen Satz, auf Englisch: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38958/is-this-a-dative-of-possession-is-this-syntax-common/38985

Comment: @PaulFrost, bitte nicht in Kommentaren antworten.

Comment: Im gesprochenen Deutsch kommen ähnlich gebaute Sätze noch heute vor: *Der Karl, das ist ein ganz schlauer*.

Answer (score 7):

Gehen wir die Bestandteile einzeln durch:

#### *dem Manne*

Das ist ein veralteter Dativ von *der Mann*.

#### *dem wurde seine Frau krank*

*seine Frau* ist das Subjekt im Nominativ, *ihm* (*dem*) ist ein Dativ-Objekt von *krank werden*.

Diese Form des Dativ-Objekts drückt aus, dass zwischen dem Subjekt des Satzes und dem Dativ-Objekt des Verbs eine Possesiv-Beziehung herrscht. Wenn ich mich nicht täusche, wird dabei regelmäßig von dem Verb eine Art Verlust ausgedrückt. Andere Beispiele für diese Konstruktion sind:

> Ihr sind alle Geschwister weggestorben.

> Ihm sind alle Erinnerungen verlorengegangen.

Das Ganze ist nicht zu verwechseln mit der heute in der Umgangssprache mitunter anzutreffenden Ersetzung des Genitivs durch den Dativ:

> Dem seine Frau wurde krank.

ist eine andere Konstruktion!

#### *Einem reichen Manne, dem*

Das ist in der Tat kein Relativsatz, *dem* ist hier kein Relativpronomen, sondern ein *Demonstrativpronomen*. Hier wird auf das Nomen (*Manne*) nochmal mit einem Pronomen verwiesen. Dies geschieht, um das Objekt besonders zu betonen. Analoge Beispiele sind:

> Der Peter, der weiß was er tut.

> Die Kartoffeln, die habe ich schon gegessen.

Ohne dieses Demonstrativpronomen würde der Satz lauten:

> Einem reichen Manne wurde seine Frau krank.

## Zusammenfassung

Durch das Demonstrativpronomen wird der Mann zum Thema des Satzes gemacht, und nicht die Frau. Dieser Fokus wird durch die Konstruktion mit dem Dativ-Verb noch verstärkt: Die Hauptbotschaft ist hier also "Einem reichen Mann ist es widerfahren, dass seine Frau krank wurde." und nicht etwa "Eine Frau wurde krank, und sie hatte einen reichen Mann."